# Fréchet derivative, partial derivatives, Jacobian, changes of bases etc...

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose $E$ and $F$ are normed vector spaces and $f: E \rightarrow F$ is Fréchet differentiable at $a \in E$. If $F$ is finite dimensional of dimension $m$, choose a base $v_1, \ldots,v_m$. $f(x)=f_1(x)v_1 + \ldots + f_m(x)v_m  $, so we have mappings $f_i : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (or into $\mathbb{C}$). It follows that the $f_i$ are Fréchet differentiable at $a$, apparently (why?). Suppose that $E$ has dimension $n$ and choose a base $u_1, \ldots, u_n$. One can form the Jacobian matrix $(Df_j(a)(u_i))$. Now apparently, if $m=n$, the determinant of the Jacobian is base independent and therefore a property of $f$. But what exactly does this mean (and how does one prove it?). Can someone point me to a good introduction into properties of Fréchet derivation?

Comment: Being a "property of $f$" in general means that if $f$ and $f'$ are two expressions which are equal (in this case, as functions), then the property evaluated using $f$ is equal to that using $f'$. In this case it means that if $f$ is expressed in coordinates, that the Jacobian determinant is the same no matter what the choice of coordinates.

Comment: It is a general theorem that the determinant of a matrix is a property of the linear map it defines, and therefore that it is preserved under change of basis. (i.e. $\det(P^{-1}AP) = \det(A)$).

Comment: Yes, but here, the Fréchet derivative is a linear map between different spaces and a change of base in both spaces will alter the determinant generally, the new matrix will be $PAM^{-1}$. What am I overlooking?

Comment: My earlier comment was wrong - I think you need the chain rule. I can try to work out the details if it's still not clear

Comment: I found another source (Laurent Schwartz Analyse II). He explicitly states that one can talk about the Jacobian determinant of f if the domain is an open subset of the range space. That's good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question:

Suppose $Df(a):E\to F$ exists. Then for each $h\in E$, we may write
$$
Df(a)(h)=(Df(a))_1(h)v_1+\dots +(Df(a))_m(h)v_m,
$$
where $(Df(a))_j:E\to \mathbb{R}$. For each $j$, we wish to prove that $Df_j(a)$ exists and $Df_j(a)=(Df(a))_j$. We know
\begin{align}
0 &=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{||f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h) ||_F}{||h ||_E} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0} ||\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{||h||_E} \Big(f_j(a+h)-f_j(a)-(Df(a))_j(h)\Big) v_j ||_F.
\end{align}
By definition of basis, this is only possible if
\begin{align}
0 &=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|f_j(a+h)-f_j(a)-(Df(a))_j(h)|}{||h||_E}.
\end{align}
This shows that $f_j$ are differentiable, and by uniqueness, we may define $Df_j(a):=(Df(a))_j$ for all $j$.